# TFS 2010 Connection Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have been working on this weird issue for a few days now and I'm going to pull my hair out! I have a PC and a server in the default WORKGROUP. I created a new collection and a new project and now I'm trying to connect from my PC to the server via VS2010. When I go to the connect team project dialog box and input my info it doesn't connect!

[image]

If I copy the preview http and input that into the browser it works fine! It asks for credinitals and the project comes up without an issue. For the fun of it I installed VS2013 team explorer and it pulls it up without an issue. What's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up going with VS2013. I'm no longer having this issue.